# Gstreamer meson build from source as a subproject of another big project

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer, meson-build, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to build Gstreamer from source using Meson as a subproject of another big project. ([Building from source using Meson](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/building-from-source-using-meson.html?gi-language=c))

The big Project`s meson contains:
`gst_dep = subproject('gstreamer')`

because the code of the original gstreamer project contains another subprojects folder that includes another gstreamer directory I am getting the next error:

```
subprojects/gstreamer/meson.build:155:4: ERROR: Recursive include of subprojects: gstreamer => gstreamer.
```

The directories structure:

```
-BigProject
    -meson.build
    -subprojects
        -gstreamer #The original gstreamer code folder
            -meson.build
            -subprojects
                -gstreamer 
                -gst-plugins-good
                -gst-plugins-bad
                etc.
```

What can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming GStreamer source repo will work.

Meson Subproject won't accept a recursive include of GStreamer repo as a subproject to add its GStreamer subproject.

That said, renaming your GStreamer repo to `gstreamer-something` and making your top meson.build's Subproject call to:

```
gst_dep = subproject('gstreamer-something')
```

Will work.

Moreover, for this renaming, you can specify the GStreamer repo name when cloning, this way:

```
git clone -b <branch> <src uri> gstreamer-something
```

Nonetheless, in case you are using a [Meson Wrap](https://mesonbuild.com/Wrap-dependency-system-manual.html#wrap-format) , you can have the Wrap file with that name and should be enough.

You can follow this [issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/issues/1773) about this issue of GStreamer that doesn't considers itself to be added as a Subproject. Hopefully they come with a rename solution or similar, soon.

Comment: Thanks, it almost worked but I didn't understand how to get the dependency of the gstreamer using gst_dep.
I need to use get variable or something like that but it doesn't work, any idea?

Comment: Subproject will get you an object which you can use to extract the dependency -- It's not exactly a dependency object already.
In the case of GStreamer, this dependency is hold into the `gst_dep` variable; and you can access this "gst_dep" via .get_variable method from the the Subproject. The returned object it's the `gst_dep` you want. Something like this:

```project('my_project', 'cpp')

gst_proj = subproject('gstreamer-something')
gst_dep = gst_proj.get_variable('gst_dep')
executable('my_project',
'my_project.cpp',
dependencies : gst_dep,
install : true)
```

Hope it helps.